# How can a variable name be used as a string in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am aware that:

```
deparse(substitute(x))
```

allows us to get the variable name "x" as a string, but in the context of a for-loop index it will return the index itself and not the variable that it refers to.

My code contains 3 examples:

```
Histogram <- function(n){
    l <- list()
    m <- list()
    s <- list()
    df <- data.frame(l, m, s, stringsAsFactors = F) #Dataframe to store output
    for(i in names(n)){
       CS <- normalmixEM(n$i) #Generates Histogram
       plot(CS, which = 2, main2 = paste(deparse(substitute(i)), "Colony Size (mm)"))

       df <- cbind(CS$lambda, CS$mu, CS$sigma)
       dev.copy(png, paste(deparse(substitute(i)),".png")) #Export histogram
       dev.off()
       }
 write.csv(df, file = paste(deparse(substitute(n)), ".csv"))
}
```

Where I would ideally like:

- The plot main title to contain the name of the variable that is in the current loop (i)
- The label of the exported plot to contain the same variable (i)
- The final exported .csv file name to be the name of the dataframe put into the function (n)

My input data is in this format:

```
>head(my_values) 
X1A  X2A  X3A  X4A  X5A  X6A  X7A  X8A  X9A X10A X11A X12A X13A X14A X15A X16A X17A X18A X19A X20A X21A X22A X23A
1 2.11 4.58 4.39 5.43 5.73 4.96 3.89 1.65 5.56 3.72 4.20 2.81 4.80 3.95 4.31 3.84 1.63 4.65 2.11 1.90 3.78 6.80 5.51
2 0.55 3.32 4.58 4.67 5.75 4.39 2.39 1.96 4.01 2.85 3.46 2.51 2.28 3.70 4.25 3.30 4.37 4.04 2.79 1.84 3.93 5.18 4.27
3 1.96 3.84 4.14 6.42 5.47 6.17 5.37 1.88 5.85 2.75 3.74 2.47 4.84 2.49 2.56 3.87 4.84 3.19 2.26 2.83 5.03 4.56 5.94
```

Is there a way to recover the variable name from the loop index before it is converted into the string?

Comment: `for(i in names(n))` will run through the values of the character vector `names(n)`. So, in each iteration, `i` will be a character vector of length 1. For `normalmixEM(n$i)`, use `normalmixEM(n[,i])`. For `paste(deparse(substitute(i)), ...` use `paste(i, ...` and the same (use `i` directly) for the `dev.copy` and `write.csv` functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @lmo `normalmixEM(n[,i])` works for calling normalmixEM. I had tried paste in this way previously, which I now see works for i. However, the same will not work for using the dataframe name: `write.csv(df, file = paste(n, ".csv"))`. Is there an alternative for dataframes?

Comment: `n` is a `list` of names, right? Use a single string...

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure what `n` is. If it is a data.frame, I would suggest that you add a second argument to your function that provides the file name you would like to provide. `Histogram <- function(n, myFileName){`. Then use this in the `paste` function in `write.table`. Alternatively, you could provide a character string with the name of the data.frame as n, and then use `get` to retrieve a copy of the data.frame inside of the function as chi-pak suggested earlier. Then you can use n in the `paste` function.